# Joining entities between two databases within same spring boot app

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My database architecture is different in QA and PROD.

- In QA : I have one database with Mutliple schemas
- In Prod : I have multiple databases

My current POC spring boot app is written for QA and hence it has one database declaration in property file and then i have mentioned `schema` name in the entity

we have an Entity defined in `Peoplepass.java` and we have reference to another entity defined in `SpotMaster.java` - both are from different datbases (but as mentioned, in QA both are from same database but from different schemas)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PEOPLE_PASS", schema = "USERS")
public class PeoplePass {

@OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "SPOT_ID", referencedColumnName = "SPOT_ID",
            insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private SpotMaster spotMaster;

    

}
```

SpotMaster Table(in different database):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPOT_MASTER", schema = "LOCATIONS")
public class SpotMaster {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SPOT_ID")
    private Integer spotId;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

   ...
}
```

The `PEOPLE_PASS` database has the `SPOT_ID` data type as Integer.. But here in the Entity it is referred another Entity (not as integer).

this works perfectly fine in `single-database-multiple-schemas` pattern.

Now when i refactored my codebase to accommodate multiple database connections ([referring this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases)), It couldn't identify
`SPOT_MASTER` table - because SpotMaster belongs to different database in PROD

**So My ask is**

1. The current entity structure - as you see above - is referring to another entity that belongs to different database
2. Is that possible ?
3. or am i left with just one option and that is to not refer another entity of different database, rather make seperate database call and stich the data ?

Comment: What about this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases?

Comment: I implemented this and then i found that an entity of one database cannot refer an entity of another database. Thats the main ask of this post.

Comment: seems like i will have to make a seperate DB call and fetch the other entity.. I can't refer it with `OneToOne` annotation to an entity thats in different database